# Merging two spatial objects in R: spCbind gives error “row names not identical”

Tags: r

```
## Importing map of Brazil
map <- readOGR ("UFEBRASIL.shp")
class (map)
plot (map, axes = F)
title ("")

## importing file with case data
data <- read.csv2 ("cases.csv")

# Recognizing the names of states as a character
map @ data $ NM_ESTADO <- as.character (map @ data $ NM_ESTADO)
map @ data $ NM_ESTADO

# Ordering the data correctly to match the order of the neighborhoods in the shape and attribute table.
head (map @ data)
head
ind <- match (map @ data $ ID, data $ ID)
ind
# Correcting accents in shape
proj4string (map) <- CRS ("+ proj = longlat + datum = WGS84 + no_defs")
Encoding (map $ NM_ESTADO) <- "UTF-8"
map $ CD_GEOCODU [is.na (map $ CD_GEOCODU)] <- 0
map1 <- spTransform (map, CRS ("+ proj = longlat + ellps = GRS80"))
summary (map1)
map1 $ NM_ESTADO

# Concatenating the map with the database
data <- data [ind,]
row.names (data) <- map1 $ NM_ESTADO
map1 <- spCbind (map1, data)
```

In this last line of command of the following error:

> Error in spCbind(mapa1, dados) : row names not identical

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is effectively a "Wall of code" post, with no description of the problem and inputs before diving into code. In the parlance of the close reason, "Providing a clear problem statement and a code attempt helps others to help you." Please [Edit] the question to frame the problem and inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a test that you haven't got the rows in the wrong order, `spCbind` tests the equality of the row names of the arguments. If they don't match it will stop:

```
> d = data.frame(ZZ=runif(56),AA=runif(56))
> ss = spCbind(scot_BNG,d) # scot_BNG from example(readOGR)
Error in spCbind(scot_BNG, d) : row names not identical
```

If you want to override this and you are sure the rows are in the right order, reassign the row names of the second argument from the first:

```
> row.names(d) = row.names(scot_BNG)
> ss = spCbind(scot_BNG,d) # scot_BNG from example(readOGR)
>
```

If the original row names are of use, store them as a column in `d` before reassigning them from the spatial object.